# Why do I get a type mismatch with a string and a Kotlin value class?

Tags: kotlin

I am using the following code-snippet right now, and wanted to use the "value class" construct to make this easier:

```
@JvmInline
value class SomeId(private val id: String)

data class SomeModel(val id: SomeId, val name: String)
data class SomeHtmlModel(val id: String, val name: String)

val id = SomeId("1")
val value = SomeModel(id,  "name")
val result = SomeHtmlModel(id, value.name)
```

Now, unfortunately this does not work, as `SomeHtmlModel` requires a string and IntelliJ tells me that there is a type mismatch. Did I understand the whole concept wrong? Can I use the value class as shown above?

From the documentation I also found this:

```
// No actual instantiation of class 'Password' happens
// At runtime 'securePassword' contains just 'String' 
val securePassword = Password("Don't try this in production")
```

This gave the impression that I could assign the `id` variable directly to a string parameter.

Comment: Guess not, that is my understanding of value classes (inline classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have misunderstood sightly. In the documentation, when comparing value classes to type aliases, they say that:

> type aliases are assignment-compatible with their underlying type [...], while inline classes are not.

So value classes aren't assignment-compatible with their underlying value, you have to unwrap them if you want to use them in this way.

They do also give an example:

```
val nameInlineClass = NameInlineClass("")
acceptString(nameInlineClass) // Not OK: can't pass inline class instead of underlying type
```